# Robocopy: Windows 2003 >>> Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2003, robocopy

I'm using Robocopy to copy/mirror a large folder from a Windows 2003 server to a Windows 2012 server in preparation for moving users off the old server to the new server.

Currently, my command is : robocopy \source\folder E: /MIR /FFT /B /XA:H /R:1 /W:5 /log+:C:\mirror-log

I'm running the robocopy command as a Scheduled Task on the Windows 2012 server.  When I created the task, I was given the option of Configure for: "Windows Server 2012 R2" or "Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2" or "Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008".  I set it to "Windows Server 2012 R2" but does it make a difference?

Also, do I need /MIR and /B?  I copied the command from a someone's post and that part wasn't explained very well.  The documentation I looked at didn't cover it either.

And I ran into a problem when a user added folders/files to the destination server and the /MIR wiped them out.  To avoid that, I should add "/XD \source\folder\sub-folder" so the sub-folder on the destination is left alone, correct?  Even if the sub-folder does NOT exist on the source?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a vague recollection that `/xd` does not prevent directories from being deleted, only from being added.  You should double-check that.  `/b` may be necessary depending on the permissions, it tells robocopy to use backup/restore privilege to bypass permission checks.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I wouldn't give the user any write permissions to the new share until you officially cut over to it.

Comment: Two masters / sources of truth won't end well.